# Cakephp multi level relationship

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have four table

course_schedules

```
id name
```

course_prices

```
id price currency_id
```

price_schedules

```
id course_schedule_id course_price_id
```

currencies

```
id name code
```

1. Course Schedule model Has many Price Schedules
2. Course price Has many Price Schedules
3. Course price belongs to Currency
4. Price Schedule belongs to Course Schedule
5. Price Schedule belongs to Course price
6. Currency has many course prices

Now all this things working fine but my problem is

In PriceSchedulesController

I can get course_schedules table details course_prices table details

But i also want to get currency code along with price Like 200 USD
    that means price_schedules indirectly dependence on Currency

There is any technique for this kind of relationship

```
public function index() {
    $this->PriceSchedule->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('PriceSchedules', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [CourseSchedule] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => course one
        )
    [CoursePrice] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [currency_id] => 1
            [price] => 200
        )
)
```

You can see in array currency_id is there but what about currency code like 200 USD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of your relations your price_schedules table already related with Currency:

```
1.price_schedules belongs to course_price
2.course_price belongs to currency
3.hence price_schedule also dependent on currency
```

When you retrieve your data you need to use contain well,e.g:

```
public function index() {
  // $this->PriceSchedule->recursive = 0;
  $this->paginate = [
     'contain'=>['CoursePrice.Currency'] // using contain this way you can easiy get that
  ];
  $this->set('PriceSchedules', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

Or you can do that from recursive property as well:

```
$this->PriceSchedule->recursive = 2;// this will retrieve all the related models
```